# How to implement "Load New Posts" like Facebook at top of UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, iphone

I like how Facebook has the "Load New Posts" at the top of the UITableView.  Is that just a header "view" to the UITableView?  And how do they load the UITableView so its hidden, i.e. the first cell of the UITableView is aligned with the top so you have to actually scroll down to see the "Load New Posts" area?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can display custom view at the top of the UITableView - see its `tableHeaderView` property.

To "hide" it initially you must scroll the table to 1st row at the top position:

```
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 4):

Neal, alternatively, you could try using the MonoTouch.Dialog framework, which adds support for a "Twitter for iPhone"-like Pull-to-Refresh system.

See:

http://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog